# I want to mention slack group into a new public channel and send automatic invitation to the people

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a new slack channel created, I am mentioning the slack group into the new channel using slack api but it is not automatically sending the invitation to the people (part of the mentioned slack group) to join the slack channel.

How can I achieve this? I am using `<!subteam^ID>` to mention the group in slack channel currently.